# Rails & CanCan: If user is logged in then allow him/her to view index page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I am using authlogic and cancan on a rails 3 application, I want to allow all logged in users to access the `users index` page, i have tried something like this but it dosent seem to be working:

ability class:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    user ||= User.new

    can :index, User if UserSession.find

    can :read, User if UserSession.find

end
```

Controller:

```
def index
    @users = User.search(params[:search]).order('username').page(params[:page]).per(1)
    authorize! :index, @users
  end




def show
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     authorize! :read, @user
     respond_to do |format|
     format.html # show.html.erb
     format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end
```

thanks

Comment: I have experience with CanCan, but I haven't used authlogic. What exactly does `UserSession.find` do?

Comment: checks to see if there is a user session present, it was recommended to me by another developer and works for other functions such as: ``can :read, User if UserSession.find`` but dosent seem to be working with the index.

Comment: Could you paste the code of controller action, and the Ability class, where it all works?

Comment: Try making it `authorize! :index, User`.

Comment: That worked thanks! u should put it as an answer so i can up vote it! Can you also please explain what was going on and why it didn't work? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, the problem was in the following code

```
authorize! :index, @users
```

Here, you're passing an Array of users to the CanCan's method, while your `can :index, User` declaration defines the authorization for a User object.

Answer (score 4):

I find it's easier to use `load_and_authorize_resource` at the top of my controllers. Then your ability class contains all the ability logic instead of having it strewn about your controllers.

ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user
      can :index, User
      can [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy], User, :id => user.id
    end
  end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    @users = User.search(params[:search]).order('username').page(params[:page]).per(1)
  end

  def show
  end

  ...

end
```

I haven't used authlogic in a while as I tend to use devise now, so I'm not sure if my sample code is authlogic ready. If you don't want to use `load_and_authorize_resource`, my code shows how to limit what users can see in the ability class, but in your code I'd change `:read` to `:show`.

Comment: `can [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]` can be replaced with `:manage`

Comment: @kishie Actually not, `:manage` means a user can take any action (including custom defined actions) on a given object.  So if for Users you have a `vote` action, `:manage` will allow users to vote whereas `[:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]` will not.